# Collision detection in Python

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm currently working on a maze game which is being written in iPython notbook. I do not have access to pygame and is therefore doing colission detection from scratch.

The code i've got so far is able to move the player around and there's a grid already there for how big the playfield is going to be.

```
from turtle import *

def line(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    pu()
    goto(x1,y1)
    pd()
    goto(x2,y2)
    pu()


setup(600,600)
setworldcoordinates(-1,-1,11,11)

class Network:

tracer(30)
ht()
for n in range(0,11):
    line(0,n,10,n)
    line(n,0,n,10)

tracer(1)

head= heading()

st()

class Figur:

register_shape("figur.gif")
shape("figur.gif")

head = heading()
pu()
setpos(9.5,9.5)

def turtle_up():
    if head != 90:
        seth(90)
        fd(1)

def turtle_down():
    if head != 270:
        seth(270)
        fd(1)

def turtle_left():
    if head != 180:
        seth(180)
        fd(1)

def turtle_right():
    if head != 360:
        seth(0)
        fd(1)

onkey(turtle_up, "Up")
onkey(turtle_down, "Down")
onkey(turtle_left, "Left")
onkey(turtle_right, "Right")

listen()

class Walls:

    def tortle():
        tracer(30)
        t1 = Turtle()
        t1.color("green")
        t1.left(180)
        t1.fd(1)
        t1.right(90)
        t1.fd(11)
    for i in range(1,4):
        t1.right(90)
        t1.fd(12)
    for i in range(1,3):
        t1.right(90)
        t1.fd(1)
    t1.left(90)
    for i in range(1,5):
        t1.fd(10)
        t1.right(90)

Walls.tortle() 
tracer(1)

update()
done()
```

Currently the walls are no near being done. I've just started on them and tried to create a wall around the compete playfield resulting in the hole area being covered in green. The picture of the turtle is one i've created myself but I think it should work without it and just take the regular turtle instead.

SO my main question is: How do I create colission detection for my turtle so it can't go through walls ?

Comment: ok, -1 right away. Could someone care to explain what I did wrong with this post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think to make a `set` of `Vec2D`s of already visited points, then compare to that every time you move. Here's a simple forward and backwards function:

```
def no_collision_forward(amount, walls):
    movement = 1 if abs(amount) == amount else -1 # If amount is negative, moving down
    for i in range(abs(amount)):
        cur_pos = pos()
        nex_pos = Vec2D(cur_pos[0], cur_pos[1] + movement)
        if nex_pos in walls:
            return  # Can return whatever
        else:
            forward(movement)

def no_collision_backward(amount, walls):
    return no_collision_forward(-amount, walls)
```

`visited_locations` should be a set of `Vec2D`s or tuples.

This is probably not the most efficient solution, but it works!